# innetHtml property not getting the css

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with two forms. For the first form css is working fine. The second form is rendering from property innerHtml. But css is not working for form2. May be this is a simple issue but i am getting stuck to find what is going wrong. Anyone please help me. I have attached an image of my html code..[image: html code]

Comment: An image is so helpful for debugging.

Comment: well i didn't find a way to add html code. few code are displaying. sorry.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting to know how to post code.

Comment: @Treadstone You didn't find a way? There's a big [?] in the edit text box's toolbar which you can get help for everything.

Comment: Please guys I need the answer...

Comment: What CSS isn't working? I don't see any CSS in your code.

Comment: @Barmar..please take a look on image in html head. I have linked jQuery mobile as source. I have told it's working fine all through the page but except form2.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't concatenate each bit of HTML separately. Construct a string that contains the whole form, and assign that to `.innerHTML`. The reason is that the browser parses the HTML after each assignment to `.innerHTML`. If you have an unclosed tag, it will "fix" it by adding the closing tag. The result is that your `<input>` elements aren't inside the form.

```
var quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
var question1 = "<h3>Question 1</h3>";
question1 += "<form id='form2'>";
question1 += "<label><input type='radio' name='choices' value='a'> A</label>";
...
question1 += "</form>";
quiz.innerHTML = question1;
```

Comment: No that is same output.